# Trying to Compare WebIOPi to the Apache Server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, embedded-linux, webiopi

http://code.google.com/p/webiopi/wiki/Tutorial_Basis

WebIOPi is a web server , much like the Apache Server, but Apache has that .htaccess file which determine the income traffic would be routed to certain file. Also the permission of the file can be also be set in .htaccess file

WebIOPi has that config file but it doesn't seem to have the routing mechanism like the .htaccess of apache or is it?

Answer (score 0):

WebIOPi doesn't have that routing mechanism, as you said.
It is based on **[BaseHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html)**.

```
if PYTHON_MAJOR >= 3:
    import http.server as BaseHTTPServer
else:
    import BaseHTTPServer
```

Take a look at **[Secure WebIOPi](https://braindump.devries.tv/index.php/raspberry-pi/94-secure-webiopi-try-2)** for a more complete comparison between BaseHTTPServer and a really secure WebIOPi implementation using Apache.